# Print Only Number On Array Data Python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a random data list like this

```
tables =
['No', 'Name', 'Job']
['1', 'A', 'A']
['', '', '']
['2', 'B', 'B']
['3', 'C', 'C']
```

how do I display only list rows that have numbers

```
['1', 'A', 'A']
['2', 'B', 'B']
['3', 'C', 'C']
```

I already tried int isinstance, but as you can see all data is a string

Comment: Python has lists, not arrays (unless you're talking about `numpy`). And you need another set of brackets around it to make a 2-dimensional list of lists.

Comment: Use `str.isnumeric()` to test if a string looks like a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.isnumeric()` to test if a string is numeric.

```
tables = [
    ['No', 'Name', 'Job'],
    ['1', 'A', 'A'],
    ['', '', ''],
    ['2', 'B', 'B'],
    ['3', 'C', 'C']
]
number_table = filter(lambda row: any(x.isnumeric() for x in row), tables)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) in a list comprehension:

```
[table for table in tables if any(x.isdigit() for x in table)]
```

**Example**:

```
tables = [['No', 'Name', 'Job'],
          ['1', 'A', 'A'],
          ['', '', ''],
          ['2', 'B', 'B'],
          ['3', 'C', 'C']]

contains_numbers = [table for table in tables if any(x.isdigit() for x in table)]
```